# How to Create Custom MarkupExtension like StaticResource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

please help me how to create a MarkupExtension looks like StaticResource of wpf,
i have:

my own class:

```
public class Item{

public string Value{get; set;}
public string Title{get;set;}
}
```

and in a Resource Dictionary i have:

```
// ...
<gpf:Item x:Key="firstone" Value="Hi" Title="Welcome"/> 
//...
```

i want to use my Item looks like:

```
// ...
<TextBlock Text="{MyEX firstone}"/>
//...
```

i tired to do this but i do not know how to finish my work:

```
    //...
    [Localizability(LocalizationCategory.NeverLocalize)]
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(string))]
    public class MyEX : MarkupExtension
    {
        public MyEX () { 
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return ??? ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want a custom `MarkupExtension` that does exactly the same as an existing one? why not simply use `StaticResource`?

Comment: Hi,thanks for ur comment; i want to create my one one cause i have some  handling operation to the property and some modification then return it.

Comment: It is recommended that you create a proper ViewModel and use DataBinding if you need to operate with `data`, while leaving XAML for UI-specific concerns.

Comment: Use reflector to see what StaticResource's ProvideValue does.

Comment: does this [Creating a Custom Markup Extension in WPF](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/03/09/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf-and-soon-silverlight) help ?

Comment: @aleksey.berezan yes it is help for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the resource key into your custom markup extension as a parameter via Constructor.

You could then, in your ProvideValue method, create a `StaticResourceExtension` and get the actual resource (in your case an instance of `Item`) by calling `ProvideValue` method.

**Quick Implementation**

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(string))]
public class MyExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public MyExtension(string resourceKey)
    {
        ResourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    string ResourceKey { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var staticResourceExtension = new StaticResourceExtension(ResourceKey);
        
        var resource = staticResourceExtension.ProvideValue(serviceProvider) as Item;
        
        return resource == null ? "Invalid Item" : String.Format("My {0} {1}", resource.Value, resource.Title);
    }
}
```

You may have to add more code in `ProvideValue` to handle design mode, etc.

Comment: Please could you tell me more about Design time, i want to get the real value at design time, i tired this
`if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
            {
                return "desing mode";
            }`
it is work well, but i want get the real value at design time. thanks

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer I am not too sure how you can get to the actual values in Design time, but you look at [IAmbientProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.iambientprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and try something with that.