# Use environment variables as source path for image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, environment-variables

I want to show an image in my wpf application and refere its source relative from enviromnent variable.

I tried '`{%test%}`'

```
<Image Source="{%test%}\SD.png" Width="24" Height="24" Margin="2" />
```

I expected the normal use of an environment variable would be expandet like (test="C:\pics") `<Image Source="C:\pics\SD.png" Width="24" Height="24" Margin="2" />` but it shows an error at compiletime:

> "`%test%`" error is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation
>   (WPF) project.

Comment: `%%`expansion is not a feature of C# or XAML strings. You have to implement that in your application. Create a view model with a string property that returns the appropriate, expanded string. Then bind the Image's Source property to the view model property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a converter to convert the file name and environment variable into a path:

```
public class EnvironmentVariableConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable((string)parameter), (string)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You should check whether the environment variable exists and if the object parameters are strings. I've skipped these checks for brevity.

Here's the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <l:EnvironmentVariableConverter x:Key="EnvironmentVariableConverter" />
    <s:String x:Key="SD">SD.png</s:String>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource SD},
        Converter={StaticResource EnvironmentVariableConverter},
        ConverterParameter=test}"
        />
</Grid>
```

The "SD.png" is now a resource so that you can bind to it without requiring a separate view model. The `ConverterParameter` passes the name of the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a view model like @Clemens mentioned, and have the calculated path exposed as a property, or you can use a converter that will parse your path string and eventually do the same calculation.
To convert %test% environment variable to its actual path you need to use
`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("test")`

documentation: [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: For using a converter, you would still have to use a Binding, so "*either use a view model*" is incorrect.

Comment: You can use [custom markup extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23372411/1997232) if you don't want to use binding. Or simply set `Image.Source` in code-behind.